# Нужна ли запятая перед словом "как" в этом предложении ?

Tags: запятая

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "как" в этом предложении? "На рисунке 1 показано КАК изменятся угол ввода в зависимости от температуры"

Answer (score 2):

"На рисунке 1 показано, КАК изменяЕтся угол ввода в зависимости от температуры" - сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая разделяет простые предложения в сложном.

Answer (score 1):

[На рисунке 1 показано] ЧТО?, {КАК изменяЕтся  угол ввода в зависимости от температуры}. Запятая нужна. Здесь две основы: ПОКАЗАНО и УГОЛ ВВОДА ИЗМЕНЯЕТСЯ.